# Failed to evaluate condition [org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension]

Tags: java, junit, junit5, testcontainers

I am getting such error with test containers
`org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate condition [org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension]: Illegal state: required test class is not present in the current ExtensionContext`

I have `@Testcontainers` in root class, that this test inherit.

Answer (score 0):

I've missed annotation on top of failing test class:

```
@Testcontainers
```